# Doesn't Google Appengine Cloud support unicode characters in response from JSP/Servlets?

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp, servlets

I am making a request to my application deployed on to Google Appengine server. The application returns a response which is in unicode. The response if I access through development server, it comes nicely as I expected it, but when I deployed on to Google production appengine server, it all comes a question marks as following 
"header":"������������������������"

if you look at the source of servlet, I ensured that following is already in place

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Please help.

Comment: What does the HTTP response header itself contain? (Firebug: *Net > HTML*). What does the browser say? (Firefox: *View > Character Encoding*)

Comment: Following is the Raw Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Date: Thu, 03 Feb 2011 11:59:55 GMT
Server: Google Frontend
Cache-Control: private, x-gzip-ok=""
Content-Length: 288

Comment: Is the problem text in coming directly from the JSP or directly from java code or is it coming indirectly from form input?  If it is from form input I've seen this before and the problem may be deep in the processing libraries -- try switching the form to multipart encoding.

Comment: This response is coming directly from Servlet. I have actually stored some data in datastore. I am fetching those data through servlet.

Comment: Then the source files containing those characters are by itself corrupted after the transfer/deploy on GWT or they are loaded/read using the wrong encoding. Since I don't go GWT I can't give a more specific answer as how to fix it.

Comment: Hey -- I have the same problem as OP. In my appengine app, using Java servlets and jsp, in local development the unicode characters render correctly. But the deployed version from appengine shows certain characters as �. I use the Google appengine plugin both for running the development server and for deploying. I would love a solution.

Comment: Oh hey, found the answer to my problem. I will post as answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried returning UTF-8 characters from a JSP page and they seem to render correctly. In the JSP I have `<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" isELIgnored="false" />` and in head `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />`. Not setting anything about content type or encoding to response in the Servlet.

I also tried retrieving and storing UTF-8 data to and from the datastore both locally and deployed and it renders all the UTF-8 characters properly on both occasions.

Here's the Servlet:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    datastoreService.put(new Example((String) req.getParameter("field"))
            .getEntity());
    resp.sendRedirect("/");
}

@Override
protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    final RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/list.jsp");
    final Iterator<Example> examples = Iterators.transform(
        datastoreService.prepare(new Query(Example.class.getSimpleName())).asIterator(),
        new Function<Entity, Example>() {
          @Override
          public Example apply(final Entity input) {
            return new Example(input);
          }
        });
  req.setAttribute("examples", examples);
  requestDispatcher.forward(req, resp);
}

public static class Example {
  private final Entity entity;

  public Example(final String field) {
    entity = new Entity(Example.class.getSimpleName());
    entity.setProperty("field", field);
  }

  public Example(Entity entity) {
    this.entity = entity;
  }

  public String getField() {
    return (String) entity.getProperty("field");
  }

  public Entity getEntity() {
    return entity;
  }
}
```

And the JSP:

```
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"
  language="java" isELIgnored="false" />
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  version="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" xml:lang="en" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Examples</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Examples</h1>
    <form action="/" method="post">
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="field" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </div>
    </form>
    <ul>
<c:forEach var="example" items="${examples}">
      <li>
        <p><c:out value="${example.field}" /></p>
      </li>
</c:forEach>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. so when I type out.println("some unicode text") it actually works. When I store some unicode data in datastore and when I store unicode data directly it works, but when I store unicode data fetched from a website and store it in datastore, I don't see it as stored in Unicode. It doesn't work even when I read that string as bytes with unicode encoding, it still doesn't store it as unicoded data

Comment: The above mentioned problem lies only in production appengine google servers. But in local machine, it works as i expected it.

Comment: I tried storing and retrieving data to and from the datastore and the UTF-8 characters appear properly. See my updated answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem as well -- certain unicode characters in my jsp (such as →) rendered fine with the development server, but not when deployed in appengine. This even though the html head contained .

The solution was to add

```
    <%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

to the top of the jsp file.